# How can I find the position of the list of substrings from the string?

Tags: python, string, indexing, substring, offset

**How can I find the position of the list of substrings from the string?**

Given a string:

> "The plane, bound for St Petersburg, crashed in Egypt's Sinai desert just 23 minutes after take-off from Sharm el-Sheikh on Saturday."

And a list of substring:

> ['The', 'plane', ',', 'bound', 'for', 'St', 'Petersburg', ',', 'crashed', 'in', 'Egypt', "'s", 'Sinai', 'desert', 'just', '23', 'minutes', 'after', 'take-off', 'from', 'Sharm', 'el-Sheikh', 'on', 'Saturday', '.']

Desired output:

```
>>> s = "The plane, bound for St Petersburg, crashed in Egypt's Sinai desert just 23 minutes after take-off from Sharm el-Sheikh on Saturday."
>>> tokens = ['The', 'plane', ',', 'bound', 'for', 'St', 'Petersburg', ',', 'crashed', 'in', 'Egypt', "'s", 'Sinai', 'desert', 'just', '23', 'minutes', 'after', 'take-off', 'from', 'Sharm', 'el-Sheikh', 'on', 'Saturday', '.']
>>> find_offsets(tokens, s)
[(0, 3), (4, 9), (9, 10), (11, 16), (17, 20), (21, 23), (24, 34),
        (34, 35), (36, 43), (44, 46), (47, 52), (52, 54), (55, 60), (61, 67),
        (68, 72), (73, 75), (76, 83), (84, 89), (90, 98), (99, 103), (104, 109),
        (110, 119), (120, 122), (123, 131), (131, 132)]
```

Explanation of the output, the first substring "The" can be found using the `(start, end)` index by using the string `s`. So from the desired output.

So if we loop through all the tuples of integers from the desired output we'll get back the list of substrings, i.e.

```
>>> [s[start:end] for start, end in out]
['The', 'plane', ',', 'bound', 'for', 'St', 'Petersburg', ',', 'crashed', 'in', 'Egypt', "'s", 'Sinai', 'desert', 'just', '23', 'minutes', 'after', 'take-off', 'from', 'Sharm', 'el-Sheikh', 'on', 'Saturday', '.']
```

I've tried:

```
def find_offset(tokens, s):
    index = 0
    offsets = []
    for token in tokens:
        start = s[index:].index(token) + index
        index = start + len(token)
        offsets.append((start, index))
    return offsets
```

Is there another way to find the position of the list of substrings from the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have no idea about the substrings, there's no way except to scan the whole text anew for each of them.

If, as it seems from data, we know that these are sequential fragments of the text, given in the textual order, it's easy to only scan the *rest* of the text after each match. There's no point to cut the text every time, though.

```
def spans(text, fragments):
    result = []
    point = 0  # Where we're in the text.
    for fragment in fragments:
        found_start = text.index(fragment, point)
        found_end = found_start + len(fragment)
        result.append((found_start, found_end))
        point = found_end
    return result
```

Test:

```
>>> spans('foo in bar', ['foo', 'in', 'bar'])
[(0, 3), (4, 6), (7, 10)]
```

This assumes that every fragment is present in the text at the right place. Your output format does not provide an example of mismatch reporting. Using `.find` instead of `.index` could help that, though only partly.

Answer (score 5):

**First solution:**

```
#use list comprehension and list.index function.
[tuple((s.index(e),s.index(e)+len(e))) for e in t]
```

**Second solution to correct the issues in the first solution:**

```
def find_offsets(tokens, s):
    tid = [list(e) for e in tokens]
    i = 0
    for id_token,token in enumerate(tid):
        while (token[0]!=s[i]):            
            i+=1
        tid[id_token] = tuple((i,i+len(token)))
        i+=len(token)

    return tid


find_offsets(tokens, s)
Out[201]: 
[(0, 3),
 (4, 9),
 (9, 10),
 (11, 16),
 (17, 20),
 (21, 23),
 (24, 34),
 (34, 35),
 (36, 43),
 (44, 46),
 (47, 52),
 (52, 54),
 (55, 60),
 (61, 67),
 (68, 72),
 (73, 75),
 (76, 83),
 (84, 89),
 (90, 98),
 (99, 103),
 (104, 109),
 (110, 119),
 (120, 122),
 (123, 131),
 (131, 132)]   

#another test
s = 'The plane, plane'
t = ['The', 'plane', ',', 'plane']
find_offsets(t,s)
Out[212]: [(0, 3), (4, 9), (9, 10), (11, 16)]
```

Comment: Nicely short but also delightfully inefficient, calling `.index()` twice.

Comment: Also, if there are repeated words, this won't work. `.index()` would always be fetching only the first instance =(

Comment: Try `s = 'The plane, plane'; t = ['The', 'plane', ',', 'plane']`

Answer (score 3):

```
import re

s = "The plane, bound for St Petersburg, crashed in Egypt's Sinai desert just 23 minutes after take-off from Sharm el-Sheikh on Saturday."
tokens = ['The', 'plane', ',', 'bound', 'for', 'St', 'Petersburg', ',', 'crashed', 'in', 'Egypt', "'s", 'Sinai', 'desert', 'just', '23', 'minutes', 'after', 'take-off', 'from', 'Sharm', 'el-Sheikh', 'on', 'Saturday', '.']


for token in tokens:
  pattern = re.compile(re.escape(token))
  print(pattern.search(s).span())
```

**RESULT**

```
(0, 3)
(4, 9)
(9, 10)
(11, 16)
(17, 20)
(21, 23)
(24, 34)
(9, 10)
(36, 43)
(44, 46)
(47, 52)
(52, 54)
(55, 60)
(61, 67)
(68, 72)
(73, 75)
(76, 83)
(84, 89)
(90, 98)
(99, 103)
(104, 109)
(110, 119)
(120, 122)
(123, 131)
(131, 132)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def spans2(text, fragments):
    result = []
    for fragment in fragments:
        found_start = text.index(fragment)
        found_end = found_start + len(fragment)
        result.append((found_start, found_end))
    return(result)
```

Test:

```
txt = "foo man bit"
frag = ["bit","man"]

spans2(txt,frag)

[(8, 11), (4, 7)]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).